# Saving Arabic tweets with related data such as tweet id ..etc

Tags: python, twitter, arabic, tweepy

I want to save arabic tweets with all related data such as tweet id, user location, user followers etc.

```
    from tweepy import Stream
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
     import json
     import sys
    import codecs
    import time
  ConsumerKey = ' '
  ConsumerSecret = ' '
  AccessToken = ' '
  AccessTokenSecret = ' '
    non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

 class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
       all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = all_data["text"]
        print(tweet.translate(non_bmp_map))

        SaveFile = codecs.open('ArabictwitDB.txt','a', "utf-8")
        SaveFile.write(all_data)


            SaveFile.write('\n')
        SaveFile.close()
        return True
    except BaseException, e:
        print 'failed',str(e)
        time.sleep(5)
def on_error(self, status):
    print status



    if __name__ == '__main__':

l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track=[unicode("رمضان","utf-8")])
```

it shows me this error

```
    failed coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found
```

but if I replace all_data

```
     SaveFile.write(all_data)
```

with tweet

```
    SaveFile.write(tweet)
```

it save only the arabic text 
How can I save all data into a file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to format it, simply

```
 SaveFile.write(json.dumps(all_data))
```

but since you didn't change anything.. why dont just save the `data` instead?

or you can access each value like you did with the `tweet`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it save the text as  \u0636\u0628\u0627\u0628 \u064a\u0647\u0648\u0646 \u0633\u064a\u0648\u0644 \u062a\u0645\u0634\u064a \u0648\u0644\u0627\u0644\u0627 ?

Comment: it's in unicode format, decode it when you load the file again